# iPhone translucent black UI dialogue: Cocoa Touch or custom?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I've been seeing this type of dialogue appear in different forms in various apps and I'm wondering whether it's a part of Cocoa Touch or a custom jobby. You can see it here, in Tweetie 2.0:

[image: Translucent Black Dialogue]

If this is a custom jobby, could anyone offer any pointers as to how to get something like this working? I'm looking to do something similar with a 'Loading...' message. Cheers guys.

**Edit**: I've just noticed Apple use a similar control for displaying ringer volume, etc., so I guess it is part of the SDK. Could somebody let me know how/where I could learn more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find many of custom UI like this alertview in the Three20 project: [here](http://github.com/facebook/three20)

Check the TTAlertViewController.

Comment: Thanks for this Yannick. It seems to be exactly what I'm after, although there doesn't seem to be much sample code for getting a TTAlertViewController operational. Could you offer a helping hand?

Comment: I have never use it yet, but I think you must create the alert with the "initWithTitle:(NSString*)title message:(NSString*)message delegate:(id)delegate" method and then call the "showInView:(UIView*)view animated:(BOOL)animated".
Otherwise I have found a tuto to do the same thing here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MBProgressHUD](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-heads-up-display-with-mbprogresshud.html)